# python convert list to json

Tags: python, json

I have a list like:

```
"subItems": [{"orderId": "OD303682818269056101","shippingFee": 0.0, "hold": False,
             "orderDate": "2015-08-19T13:57:48+05:30", "quantity": 1}]
```

i want to convert it to dict like:

```
new_dict = {"orderId": "OD303682818269056101",
            "shippingFee": 0.0,
            "hold": False,
            "orderDate": "2015-08-19T13:57:48+05:30",
            "quantity": 1}
```

how to do that?
I tried 
`dict(subItems)` but didn't worked.

Comment: new_dict = subItems[0]?

Comment: its already in a dictionary inside the list. you just need to acces it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already is a dictionary, inside a list, at the first index (index 0). To access the dictionary, you simply need to get the first item (at index 0). To get the first item of any list you use the syntax `L[0]` so this is what you need:

```
new_dict = subItems[0]
```